# Change the package name for the app published in Google play store

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have launched my first app yesterday. Later I realized that package name looks weird from its application, how can I change it?

It involves Firebase real-time database with authentication support. If I create new project with same content with different package name, can I use the same Firebase authentication data and real-time database?
Should I change Google service JSON file?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about app stores are off-topic. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/6296561

Comment: Have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#register-app . You cannot change the package name in firebase. Maybe initializing Firebase yourself might help. Have a look at https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/take-control-of-your-firebase-init-on.html . You can get the values shown in the guide by looking at the Firebase JSON file.

Comment: You can test and let me know if it works. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change package name, it will be a new app.

You can create new project, with new package name, but you have to update all services (Firebase, etc..) and upload as a new app in Google Play Store.

Comment: Can I use the same firebase real-time database data?i.e link new app to same firebase project

Comment: Can you elaborate Where should I change it?